# Foucs on the new entered row in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a `DataGridView` which its `DataSource` is a `DataTable`.

When I add a new record I refill the `DataGridView`with a `DataTable` to update rows.

My problem is when the `DataGridView` updated , the focus go to the first row while I need the focus to set on the new row.

**Notice:** Changing focus to the last row will not resolve it because the data in the sql database is sorted alphabetical , so every new record the data re-sorting and then the new row will not be the last one.

I Use Identity as key of my table.

Comment: If you use Identity as key, you can find the row having maximum value for key and select it.

Comment: yes i'm using identity as key ... so how to set the selected row at the maximum value in it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Identity as key, you can find the row having maximum value for key and select it. I suppose you have a column named `Id` in `DataTable`. So you can do something like this:

```
var max = dt.Compute("MAX(Id)", "");
var row = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(x => !x.IsNewRow)
    .Where(x => ((DataRowView)x.DataBoundItem)["Id"].Equals(max)).FirstOrDefault();
this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = row.Cells[0];
```

Just for example, create a test data table this way:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "X");
    dt.Rows.Add(10, "Y");
    dt.Rows.Add(100, "Z");
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```